# On Numbers (Mac), how can I export (save) a chart using Python or Apple Script

Tags: numbers

I have a numbers chart with mulitple plot in a sheet.
And I would like to save that chart in jpeg/pdf using python or applescript.

Answer (score 0):

With AppleScript:

```
activate application "Numbers"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Numbers"
        click menu item "PDF…" of menu 1 of menu item "Export To" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Note that "…" is one character (ellipsis). If you're trying to use three dots "..." it will not work. The script only navigates you to the 'Export Your Spreadsheet' dialog. Do you want the script to set the file name, saving location and so on?

Comment: Thanks. I just want to save a specific chart (Graph) inside a sheet and save that chart in folder (in jpeg or whatever).

Comment: really ... Too bad ..  There should be a way for me to get that pictures saved ...

Comment: If you have an image (a jpg for example) inserted into the document you can access it by changing the file extension .numbers to .zip. After extracting the zip, the images are inside the Data folder. But charts work different, they're not stored as generated images.

Comment: I have tried the below ...                                                                             activate application "Numbers"

tell application "Numbers"
 activate
 tell document 1
  tell active sheet
   set SheetName to name
   set theChart to first chart
   set theChartName to its name
   set the selectedChart to ¬
    (the first chart)
   set theImagePath to (path to desktop as text)
   export selectedChart to theImagePath as PDF
     
  end tell
 end tell
end tell